# Django multiple sessions cookie domain for multiple subdomains

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, subdomain

My Django app handles multiple subdomains like "first.domain.com", "second.domain.com" etc.

My SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN is ".domain.com" to handle multiple subdomains.

So when I access my app from first.domain.com or second.domain.com, I can see the **same session cookie** from both subdomains.

*So my question is;* is it possible to set SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to "first.domain.com" when it's being accessed from "first.domain.com" and "second.domain.com" when it's being accessed from "second.domain.com" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting or set it to `None`. Django will automatically use the current domain.

Comment: @Ludwik can you tell me how I can enable sessions to work on Subdomains for a Single site I have tried your solution but no luck I am using Django==1.8.8

Comment: @vaibhavjain my solution would add a separate cookie (=separate session) on every subdomain. Most likely that's not what you want. You need to set this setting to `.yourdomain.com` (note the dot at the beginning).